# Start scala repl loop from code using sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to start a scala repl loop (using breakif) and I'm building/running from SBT and I've tried to follow the advice in the FAQ but haven't been able to get it to work.

Could someone give an example of the MyType which is being used to configure the settings as described, "MyType is a representative class that should be included on the interpreter's classpath and in its application class loader"

https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/FAQ (under "How do I use the Scala interpreter in my code?")

Using scala 2.9.1 and sbt 0.11

Thanks

Comment: Can you link to the stuff you are citing, in particular 'MyType'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FAQ links to a [background discussion](https://gist.github.com/404272), which demonstrates how `MyType` is actually used,

*Usage:*

```
val settings = new Settings()
settings.embeddedDefaults[MyType]
```

*Inside SBT:*

```
def embeddedDefaults[T: Manifest] {
  val loader = implicitly[Manifest[T]].erasure.getClassLoader
  explicitParentLoader = Some(loader) // for the Interpreter parentClassLoader
  getClasspath("app", loader) foreach { classpath.value = _ }
  getClasspath("boot", loader) foreach {
     bootclasspath.value = settings.bootclasspath.value + File.separator + _
  }
}
```

So `MyType` is only used to help SBT find the appropriate classloader. Presumably, you can choose `MyType` to be an arbitrary class from your project that you want to have available from the interpreter. This is basically what the FAQ means when it says: *MyType is a representative class that should be included on the interpreter's classpath and in its application class loader*.

Comment: This works for a regular SBT project, but isn't working with a xsbt-web-plugin project

Comment: @GhostM, Sorry, not familiar with xsbt-web-plugin. You'll probably get a better response on the [SBT mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/simple-build-tool). Once you figure it out, please post your answer here, and consider updating the SBT wiki.