# Scala SBT: scala.tools.nsc isn't running

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a problem with **scala.tools.sbt**

**scala file**

Here I used parser functionality to make abstract syntax tree of code `2 + 3`

```
import scala.tools.nsc._
object Main extends App {
    var i = new Interpreter
    println(i.parse("2 + 3"))
}
```

**SBT configuration**

```
name := "scalaSample"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.9.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.7.1" % "test"

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.9.1"
```

**Error**

> Failed to initialize compiler: object scala not found.
>   ** Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
>   ** For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
>   ** object programatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.
>
> [error] (run-main) java.lang.NullPointerException
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   scala.tools.nsc.CompilationUnits$CompilationUnit.
>   (CompilationUnits.scala:16)   at
>   scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ExprTyper$codeParser$.applyRule(ExprTyper.scala:22)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ExprTyper$codeParser$.stmts(ExprTyper.scala:36)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ExprTyper$$anonfun$parse$2.apply(ExprTyper.scala:47)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ExprTyper$$anonfun$parse$2.apply(ExprTyper.scala:46)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.reporters.Reporter.withIncompleteHandler(Reporter.scala:46)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ExprTyper$class.parse(ExprTyper.scala:46)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$exprTyper$.parse(IMain.scala:1012)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.parse(IMain.scala:1013)    at
>   eu.semantiq.scalaToJS.Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:7)   at
>   scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)    at
>   scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
>     at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:60)    at
>   scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:60)     at
>   scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)   at
>   scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:30)
>     at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:60)   at
>   eu.semantiq.scalaToJS.Main$.main(Main.scala:5)    at
>   eu.semantiq.scalaToJS.Main.main(Main.scala)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1  at
>   scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)

**In scala REPL everything works**

> Welcome to Scala version 2.9.0.1 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java
>   1.6.0_23). Type in expressions to have them evaluated. Type :help for more information.
>
> scala> **import scala.tools.nsc._**
>
> import scala.tools.nsc._
>
> scala> **var i = new Interpreter**
>
> warning: there were 4 deprecation
>   warnings; re-run with -deprecation for details warning: there were 1
>   deprecation warnings; re-run with -deprecation for details
>
> i: scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter = scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter@786bfd73
>
> scala> **println(i.parse("2 + 3"))**
>
> **Some(List(2.$plus(3)))**

I feel really sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to xsbt's [FAQ](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/FAQ):

> sbt runs tests in the same JVM as sbt itself and Scala classes are not
>   in the same class loader as the application classes.

And there's more:

> The key is to initialize the Settings for the interpreter using
>   embeddedDefaults.

The example that is given there uses some arbitrary type `MyType`. In fact, you can use any of your types to help sbt find the appropriate class loader (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8466657/271678)).

Hence, your code should look like this:

```
import scala.tools.nsc._

trait Foo // Arbitrary type added to get stuff working

object Main extends App {
    val settings = new Settings
    settings.embeddedDefaults[Foo]
    val interpreter = new Interpreter(settings)
    println(interpreter.parse("2 + 3"))
}
```